# Installing Ruby 2.6.6 or 2.6.7 on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, homebrew, rbenv

Recently, I've been trying to work on a Rails project on my local workspace. I just swapped laptops (Macbook pro M1), and since then, I have been unable to install Ruby 2.6.6 and/or 2.6.7. Here is the error output when I run `rbenv install 2.6.6`:

```
Last 10 log lines:
compiling ../.././ext/psych/yaml/dumper.c
compiling ../.././ext/psych/yaml/reader.c
compiling ../.././ext/psych/yaml/emitter.c
compiling ../.././ext/psych/yaml/parser.c
linking shared-object date_core.bundle
5 warnings generated.
linking shared-object zlib.bundle
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object psych.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

I then checked rbenv install --list and it lists 2.5.9, 2.6.7, 2.7.3, and 3.0.1. So, I tried installing 2.6.7, but that did not work either. Apparently, the installation for Ruby 2.6.7 is a known bug and has no fix as of yet ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67023479/error-installing-ruby-2-6-7-on-mac-os-how-to-resolve), [link2](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17777)).

If anyone has had experience with this issue, please let me know of some solutions. I have been stuck on this error for the entire day and I am quite desperate :(.

Comment: Have you tried using RVM instead of rbenv?

Answer (score 10):

Ruby 2.6.6 does not support MacBooks with M1 chips.

If you still want to install, you can try the way I have installed:

```sh
# asdf
RUBY_CFLAGS=-DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC asdf install ruby 2.6.6

# rbenv
RUBY_CFLAGS=-DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC rbenv install 2.6.6
```

If this does not work, there are other options on the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1699).

Comment: This did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for me on MacOS 13.1

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers did not work for me on an M1 chip.  However, this did

`RUBY_CFLAGS="-w" rbenv install 2.6.7`

Comment: Note, however, that if you have updated to macOS Ventura, even this will not work.

Comment: I which I'd known that before updating to Ventura! I HATE APPLE!!!

Comment: As far as I can tell it works (again?).  I had to use it recently on a Ventura 13.1 install (M2).

Comment: As of today and MacOS 13.2.1 on M2 chip, the was the only solution that worked for me. Thx man

Answer (score 3):

if the `rbenv install --list-all` is missing `2.6.6`, try to re-install from the beginning while updating `ruby-build`.

```sh
# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc

# Install Ruby
rbenv install 2.6.6
rbenv global 2.6.6
ruby -v
```

Comment: the "beginning" of what?