# rvm install 2.6.7 always failed on Apple M1 mac

Tags: ruby, compiler-errors, rvm, apple-m1

I always get bellow error on my M1 mac while `rvm install 2.6.7`

[image]

```
me@xx ~ % rvm install 2.6.7
ruby-2.6.7 - #removing src/ruby-2.6.7 - please wait
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/11.5/x86_64/ruby-2.6.7.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.7, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.6.7 - #downloading ruby-2.6.7, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.6.7 - #extracting ruby-2.6.7 to /Users/me/.rvm/src/ruby-2.6.7 - please wait
ruby-2.6.7 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-2.6.7 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-2.6.7 - #compiling - please wait
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/me/.rvm/log/1629787822_ruby-2.6.7/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Please checkout my article which resolve all issue realted to apple m1 - https://medium.com/@vishalsadriya1224/how-to-install-postgresql-node-with-nvm-ruby-with-chruby-rails-in-macbook-pro-m1-chip-4612e0a50260

Answer (score 11):

Yes, this is a known issue upstream: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17777
ruby-build is also tracking this issue: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1489

The work around is to run the following code, and install ruby 2.6.7 again:

```
$ export warnflags=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration
$ rbenv install 2.6.7
```

-or-

```
$ CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rbenv install 2.6.7
```

Looks like this can also impact gem installation with native extensions (mysql2 is one of those):

```
gem install <GEMNAME> -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

Referenced: [Error installing ruby 2.6.7 on mac os - how to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67023479/error-installing-ruby-2-6-7-on-mac-os-how-to-resolve)

Comment: For those who have trouble using `rbenv` follow this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-18-04) first

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue in RVM, following solution worked for me.

```
CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rvm install 2.6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, the easiest way is to install 2.6.9 later version, everything will be ok.

If you really need older version ruby, you can try to use openssl@1.0. If it still is error. Maybe see this blog [enter link description here](https://medium.com/@agrawal.mayank1996/installing-old-ruby-versions-in-mac-m1-477a212f8bf2#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjA3NGI5MjhlZGY2NWE2ZjQ3MGM3MWIwYTI0N2JkMGY3YTRjOWNjYmMiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.vQdaIipPebHdo_KfUq6agZdZnfIJNFYVnMUjQboTkJBUfFkU0hUJCkl8t2f9v8f1BMjVTTzegNyqaU6Srxw9i_tgpJzGT3cN0H2ScD0Ek2llpgMKfkPohvsh0ehkmNh-XKDRcmb61FTAuBF0z0s5gZv6Hu0N78u5kCrY2og_9ggs47NBfVXJbQg38Len3bLBuyD8Ql8f-h6hOxegWo5Y_30xll57y_MvggCws_Fn9mKgEZEKQDT5uBVLzHWlLtZwdjXtwmaci5DcBJFn3_TpZzxsJY85f6LvywCDlWhbJfTdxH3WGGJ85FV0w-ZtPRZxus4DMhYm39CvK3fJUhQ1Ow), which doesn't use arm one.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this it works for me.

```
brew install openssl
rvm install 2.6.7 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
```

Comment: You can use this
rvm install 2.5.3 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have homebrew installed on an M1, these two steps seem to solve the issue.

```
brew install libffi

LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include" rvm install 2.7.7
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [this Issue](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5033) on Github, the issue is due to the version of openssl that is used. I had to download an old version of openssl and bind it to the ruby installation.

You can download the required version [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases/tag/OpenSSL_1_0_2u).

Then run these commands:

```
$> tar -xzf openssl-OpenSSL_1_0_2u.tar.gz
$> cd openssl-1.0.2u
$> ./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc --prefix=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0
$> make
$> make test
$> sudo make install
$> rvm install 2.6.7 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0
```

Update the version you want to use for ruby in the last command.

You will maybe need to run:

```
$> rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```